# passing data to ionic 5 custom element tag

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

my ionic 5 app has a side menu and tabs. Each page can have different contents for the side menu and the tabs. I don't want to be duplicating the ion-menu in each page so I created a header component like so (I also do one for the tabs):

HEADER COMPONENT:

```
<ion-menu contentId="content">
   <ion-header>
     <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
       <ion-title>{{pageObj.title}}</ion-title>
     </ion-toolbar>
   </ion-header>
   <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
       <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let page of pageObj.pages">
         <ion-item [routerLink]="page.url" routerDirection="root" [class.active-item]="selectedPath.startWith(page.url)">
          <ion-icon>{{page.icon}}</ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
             {{page.title}}
           </ion-label>
         </ion-item>
       </ion-menu-toggle>

     </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
 </ion-menu>
```

Now I use this header component in app.component.html like so:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <ion-router-outlet id="content"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

And app.component.ts:

```
...........
.........
export class AppComponent {
  pageObj: any = '';
  selectedPath = '';
  pages = [
    {
      title: 'Become a Member',
      url:   '/pages/membership'
    },
    {
     title: 'Make a Posts',
     url:   '/pages/posts'
   }
  
  ]


  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router: Router
  ) {
       this.initializeApp();
       this.pageObj.title = 'Menu';
       this.pageObj.pages = this.pages;
       this.router.events.subscribe((event:RouterEvent) => {
       if (event && event.url) {
         this.selectedPath = event.url;
       }
     })
  }

.........
........
```

So the problem is  requires variables (pageObg) that exist in app.component.ts. I am not sure how to pass those variables? I believe I can do something like this:

```
<app-header [pageObj]="pageObj"><app-header>
```

but I am not sure how this works! Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, but that is not enough. You need to create the corresponding `@Input pageObj` property in the child component's class. That should be sufficient in your case.

This is the comprehensive guide on Component Interaction, please refer to the first section on "input binding" at this link: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding